# "while" loop not iterating correctly

Tags: java

I am supposed to print the following output by using loops:

```
            1 
          2 1 
        3 2 1 
      4 3 2 1 
    5 4 3 2 1 
  6 5 4 3 2 1 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The highest number in this pattern (in this example, 7) is determined by user input. Here is the applicable code for the pattern:

```
index=patternLength+1; n=1;     //These values are all previously intitialized
while (index!=1) {
    index--;
    printSpaces((index*2)-2);   //A static method that prints a certain number of spaces
    while(n!=1) {
        n--;
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    n=patternLength+1-index;
}
```

And here is the incorrect output for the user input "7":

```
        1 
      2 1 
    3 2 1 
  4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1
```

There are two blank lines preceding the incorrect output; these lines have the correct number of spaces necessary for the complete/correct pattern, but for some reason, the actual numbers start printing too "late" in the loop.  *In other words, the spaces that appear before the "1, 2 1" in the correct example are in the incorrect output. It's some of the numbers that are missing and make the incorrect example incorrect.*

Comment: On the first iteration, `n=1` so `while(n!=1)` skips immediately and no numbers are printed on the first row. --- At the end of the first iteration, `index = patternLength+1 - 1 = patternLength`, so `n=patternLength+1-index = patternLength+1-patternLength = 1`, so on the second iteration it will again skip the `while(n!=1)` loop and not print any numbers. --- Which part of that is confusing you, and why couldn't you see that for yourself with a **debugger**?

Comment: A. This is the "best" that I could do; when I try tweaking the loop controls, I get even stranger outputs (I can get examples if you'd like). B. I've not yet learned to use a debugger @Andreas

Comment: Perhaps I should change the title to "not iterating the way I _want_ it to".

Comment: Ask yourself what the value of `n` is supposed to *be*. What does the value mean? Is it the count of numbers to print on the current row? If yes, the initial value of `1` is good, but loop condition `while(n!=1)` is bad, since you want it to iterate once for a value of `1`. --- And you should then re-check the formula for calculating `n` for the second iteration, because you'd want `n` to be `2` on the second iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it.

```
    index=patternLength+1; n=1;int nSetter=1;
    //Loop C
    System.out.println("Pattern C:");
    while (index!=1) {
        index--;
        printSpaces((index*2)-2);
        while(n!=0) {

            System.out.print(n + " ");
            n--;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        nSetter++;
        n = nSetter;
    }
```

My problem was that my "n" needed to go both up and down, so the extra variable "nSetter" seems to have solved that, although this may be a round-about solution. Whatever. Thanks to @Andreas for pointing me in the correct direction and @JohnKugelman for the helpful edit.

Comment: I suggest you accept your own solution - it's an encouraged practice

Comment: @AlexYu thanks, I just tried and it says that I have to wait two days. I'll accept it if I don't forget.

Comment: Ah, OK. It's easy to not forget: you can always inspect your questions and answers on your profile page

Answer (score 1):

***Please try this code your second while loop is not correct.***

```
int index = patternLength + 1;
        int n = 2;     //These values are all previously intitialized
        int i = 1;
        while (index != 1) {
            index--;
            printSpaces((index * 2) - 2);   //A static method that prints a certain number of spaces
            while (n != 1) {
                n--;
                System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            i++;
            n = i+1;
        }
```

Comment: Hmm...my code appears to work fine. Could you elaborate? Thanks for the answer!